# Django - local variable 'secs' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, html, django

I've been trying to handle this but I have no clue how

I have a form where I'm getting `secs`

```
form role="form" action="" method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}
          <br>
          <input type="number" name="secs" min="0" max="999" maxlength="3" class="form-control no-spinners" placeholder="Programar...">
          <br>
          <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="w3-btn w3-large w3-green" style="width:30%"> Aceptar </button>
        </form>
```

in my **views.py**

```
def streaming(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        secs = request.POST['secs']
        print secs
        programarTiempo(secs)
        messages.info(request, 'Iniciando streaming en...' + secs + ' segundos')
        time.sleep(float(secs))
        return redirect('streaming')
    return render(request, "straming.html", {"secs":secs})
```

When I got to my .html I got the following error:

> UnboundLocalError at /streaming/ local variable 'secs' referenced
>   before assignment

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: If request.method is not "POST", then `secs` is never defined, so when you try to call `render()`, you get the error.

Comment: Yes I know that part, but if I define secs outside the post method I won't get the correct value of `secs`

Comment: You're getting the value from `request.POST['secs']`, which _doesn't exist_ when request.method isn't POST.  So I don't know what value you could possibly expect to get...

Comment: Do you want the value of `secs` from the _previous_ execution of the function?

Comment: Try accepting it in query string if the request is GET. Like this /my/app/myroute?secs=3. Then in your controller, you can have `sec = request.args["secs"]`

Comment: For example say I define secs outside the function as None , `secs = None`, if I remove the `secs` from the `render()` method I'm getting the correct value, if I call the `render()` with `secs`I'm getting `None`because of the request.Post `method`, I expect the correct one. That's what I want to reach.

Comment: If `secs` is passed to your page, and it's a GET request. it has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is if the method is not Post, it goes to return (last line) which has secs variable but you defined it in the if condition